# UTF-8 in Jsoncpp Lib

Tags: c++, json, jsoncpp

I have a problem while using the jsoncpp lib in a project. I tried to read, edit and write a local json files. The problem i have, is that i can't find a way to get the encoding of writing/reading to UTF-8. It always uses ASCII. This is an Example Json File:

`{"Name": "Müller"}`

I'm using it like this:

```
std::ifstream ifs;
std::ofstream ofs;
Json::CharReaderBuilder builder;
Json::StreamWriterBuilder wbuilder;
const std::unique_ptr<Json::StreamWriter> writer(builder.newStreamWriter());
Json::String errs;

parseFromStream(builder, ifs, &root, &errs);

string name = root["Name"].asString();
//if i try to use this data in my wxWidgets Gui now, the Output would be sth like Mï¿½ller

root["Straße"] = "Ahornweg 5";

writer->write(root, &ofs);
```

If i use it like this the jsonfile would look like this:

`{ "Stra\u00dfe": "Ahornweg 5", "Name":"Mï¿½ller"}`

Hope someone can help me. Every help is appreciated.

Comment: `Stra\u00dfe` is exactly that `can help me` with what?

Comment: Yes its the same value. but encoded differently. What I want in my Jsonfile is Straße and not Stra\u00fde. Because I cant acces it again with using root["Straße"]. I need to open it with root["Stra\u00dfe] and this is not working for this exact project

Comment: You may need to use a different library. I didn't see anything in the jsoncpp docs about encodings there. I read docs for rapidjson which has info about encodings but even then I can't tell if it meets your requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone in the future wondering, reading this question, it took me some time since I'm a beginner in coding, but it has something to do with the encoding you use in your IDE. Make sure that it's really UTF-8!